# Can Webpack dynamic load a UMD module on client-side?

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamic, load, umd

I did it with Systemjs, but the config is the worst part of it. I need to download a UMD library in the browser and render it as part of the application, but everything in Webpack is self-contained. Is it possible? Did it work for someone?

I need this to do some good stuff with Angular Universal but I don't want to keep using SystemJS.

Comment: If I remember correctly yes you can, I did it. However I would like to provide you a working example in a dedicated answer, can you add your current webpack configuration to your question and the name of the library ?

Comment: I'm using ng serve for the moment. I will eject it if necessary. The library is developed by us and we use ng-packagr to bundle it.

Comment: Sry, ng serve meaning angular/cli.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to load an umd library separately (not in your bundle) and still access it in your bundle through the global window, you can either add an import loader or an export loader: see https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming.

Otherwise you shouldn't encounter any problem importing a umd module with Webpack.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the ability to do this on the client-side, without my webpack knowing previously about the library. For what I saw, I need to do some setup and build everything together first and let webpack index the files, no?

Comment: Btw, thanks for your help! I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: What do you mean by client side ? Dynamic imports with `import()ˋ?

Comment: Dynamic imports on the browser. I need to build a method, like the `Using host-specific mechanisms` from [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) that get a UMD, resolve its dependencies and bring the module to whatever context it is needed.

Comment: `import('my-umd-module').then({default: myUmdModule} => { /* do something */ })` should also work out of the box with webpack. What have you tried, what didn't work ?